# Need assistance Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to write a formula on excel. Please assist with a formula to calculate the actual output, if target heads produce target out put, what formula do i need to get the actual output

```
Target Heads    Target Output      Actual Heads     Actual Output
     7                 500             5
     8                 600             4
     9                 230             10
     5                 150             4
     6                 140             6
```

Comment: (Actual Output) = (Actual Heads) * (Target Output) / (Target Heads)

Comment: What have you tried? How is the result not what you want?

Comment: You have not explained how *actual output* is calculated.  The name itself would suggest it's simply a data input (i.e. real measured value, not calculated).  It sounds like you need [basic spreadsheet help](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-formulas-step-by-step-tutorial-3123636)

Answer (score 0):

Target Output divided by Target Heads would give you the expected amount for 1 person.  You can then multiply that figure by actual heads to give you an Actual Output value (although I'd call it Expected Output rather than Actual Output, as the use of "actual" for this column suggests a figure that has been achieved and would therefore be manually input as opposed to being calculated).

Assuming your data starts in A1, then the formula in D2 would be =B2/A2*C2